# Properly use of jar command

Tags: java

I wanted to use java commands so I searched a lot in the internet.
What I found was to make a new user variable with the name `PATH` and value `%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` .
After restarting I wrote in cmd: `java` and it showed:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)


or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

-splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.
```

Then I typed in cmd: `jar` and it showed:

```
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why does it recognised the first command but not the second one?

My operating system is Windows 8 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

`jar.exe` is part of `JDK` not `JRE`. Point path to JDK 7.

---

Just go to the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` and search for `jar.exe`. You will never find it there.

The first comment `java` works fine because `java.exe` is present in JDK and well as JRE.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [visit](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `jar` command ships with the JDK, and not with the JRE. Install a JDK and add it to your PATH.